# Improper Integral in terms of another variable

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

I need help evaluating the following improper integral:

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{(x^2+1)(x^k+1)}$$

---

**My attempt:**

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{x^{2+k}+x^k+x^2+1}$$

WLOG, Let $k = 0$. Then we have:

$$\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{(x^2+1)}$$

This is equal to $\frac{\tan^{-1}(x)}{2}$ evaluated at infinity which is equal to $\frac{\pi}{4}$. Is this correct? Do I lose generality by letting $k = 0$?

Comment: Yes. I don't know what you need it for, but if the k is there it must be because you want to vary that parameter and have the answer to be a function of k. By letting k equal zero you are losing all that generality

Comment: I am not given a value for k.

Comment: If this is not correct, maybe I can compute the integral in terms of k.

Comment: I think that is what is asked. Try to see if you can get to an expression that only depends on k for the value of the integral. It is good that you know one value (where k=0), in case you need it to calculate some recursion or some constant term... Depending on how you solve it

Comment: Use complex analysis.

Comment: Contour integration?

Comment: Yes - k is an integer. Sorry, I did not include that. There are no other assumptions other than this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

---

Let $\alpha$ be any real number.

$$\begin{align}
I{\left(\alpha\right)}
&=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\left(1+x^{2}\right)\left(1+x^{\alpha}\right)}\\
&=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{y^{\alpha}}{\left(1+y^{2}\right)\left(1+y^{\alpha}\right)}\,\mathrm{d}y;~~~\small{\left[x=y^{-1}\right]}\\
&=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\left(1+y^{2}\right)}\left[1-\frac{1}{1+y^{\alpha}}\right]\,\mathrm{d}y\\
&=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{1+y^{2}}-\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\left(1+y^{2}\right)\left(1+y^{\alpha}\right)}\\
&=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{1+y^{2}}-I{\left(\alpha\right)},\\
\end{align}$$

$$\implies I{\left(\alpha\right)}=\frac12\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{1+y^{2}}.$$

That is to say, your integral $I{\left(\alpha\right)}$ is in fact independent of $\alpha$!